# How to create a Segment control with two rows?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uisegmentedcontrol

My goal is to create a Segment control with two rows.

Here is an image to paint a picture of my words.  [image]

I've tried viewing the properties of the UISegmentControl and I thought there would something likes rows or lines, but I can't seem to find anything of the sort. Is this in the scope of a SegmentControl, or is this something that I would have to do in a custom view?

I looked through OBJ C code, but I'm slightly confused as to what he is doing.

```
[_segmentedControl.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * obj,     NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
[obj.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *_tempLabel = (UILabel *)obj;
        [_tempLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    }
 }];     
}];
```

I don't see anything called enumerateObjectsusingBlock, or setNumberOfLines as properties of Segmentcontrol.

Comment: This is a custom control, not UISegmentControl.

Comment: Can try creating a view with 6 buttons...

Comment: @JAL This question was not answered in Swift, only OBJ C. So I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: @bradfordgray Either way, your question is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow, since you posted an image and asked "How do I build this?"  If you edit your question to show your attempt at solving the problem and what specifically isn't working, I will consider reopening your question.

Comment: Sure, I will give more detail. I just wanted to get straight to the point, but I get you are saying.